# Plot decision boundaries in highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts, classification, supervised-learning

attached you see a decision boundary graph of a classification algorithm made in ggplot(from [this](http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~lepennec/R/Learning/Learning.html) great article)I was curious about if it is possible to replicate such graphs in highcharter, or more specifically: Is it possible to create custom boundary lines / areas for different classification algorithms? I would highly appreciate an example and thank you for your support.

[image: Decision Boundary]

Comment: While I don't see the figure, my guess would be that it is possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Highly appreciate it. I just added the picture as well as the corresponding source in the question. Would it be possible for you to provide a simple example with sample data in highcharter?